# Irresponsible answers on SO, should we flag them?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, flags

In case of a 'working' solution but a dangerous one, should I flag it as 'Requires Moderator attention'?
I see lots of these, mostly server side web related answers with serious security problems.
I've now seen one ending with "And you're done", as in saying "Copy->Paste->Deploy on production".

I am not sure if I should flag this kind of answers or just let the community do it's magic. It seems like in this case the community did it's magic as this answer was marked as accepted and was then unmarked after a few comments.

**UPDATE**: Link to an example answer: [PHP: Is there a correct method for saving configuration data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218438/php-is-there-a-correct-method-for-saving-config-data/2218487#2218487)

Comment: Linky. No way to judge without some idea of how bad you're talking...

Comment: Like security or possible scalability or performance issues ?

Comment: @dmckee: Added a link to the example which ending with "And you're done"

Comment: @Andrei Rinea: Security issues. Performance issues should obviously be handled by the community, no?

Comment: I'd just comment and in egregious cases down-vote as well.

Comment: Yup, this is definitely a down-vote case.

Comment: +1 because of your comment on Mark's answer ("the community did work its magic on this case (it was initially marked as the correct answer before I commented on it)")

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Php is not one of my skills, but this looks like it is mostly fragile and contrary to good practices.

I'd just go with a down vote and explanatory comment.

Answer (score 3):

**Let the Community Work its Magic**

It's sitting at the bottom of the page with a -2, with lots better (and clearer) answers above it.

Comment: A comment or a direct edit in the answer, stating the danger of the answer, would add to this. A downvote doesn't prevent the answer from being visible, and associated to the question. Warning potential other viewers is necessary.

Comment: Gnoupi, fine point!

Comment: Yeah, the community did work its magic on this case (it was initially marked as the correct answer before I commented on it)