# How to avoid solutions in answers with foundational accessibility issues, in line with Stack Exchange’s policies

Tags: discussion, answers, accessibility

Stack Overflow, User Experience and other Stack Exchange (SE) sites are where developers come to get unstuck with their issues, and to learn developing. This target audience are the people who shape our technological future. This future, therefore, is very much influenced by the solutions suggested presented on the sites.

Unfortunately, most developers end up publishing software that excludes people, foremost those with disabilities, due to the inaccessible nature of their solutions.

Of course, there is the tag *accessibility* on several sites, but people asking there already do care. It would be necessary to sensitise those who never considered that aspect of development, who are learning.

So I was wondering how I could start making people aware of these issues in the solutions proposed on the Q&A sites here.

My maxim would be: **There should not be examples on SE that have foundational accessibility issues.** Or, if there are, the reader should be aware of the issues before using the solution. Just as the Mozilla Developer Network does. Their code examples are quite accessible, and they systematically add notes on accessibility.

So I considered the following, as a personal initiative:

1. Leaving comments on accepted answers pointing out the issues
2. Leaving these comments on the question
3. Correcting the issues in the (accepted) answer, even if they are not directly linked to the question
4. Adding an accessibility disclaimer to the (accepted) answer explaining the issues
5. Adding another answer that offers a more accessible solution

Are there issues with SE’s policies in doing this? Am I missing other options?

Comment: I would only do 3 if there are really minor changes needed to acomplish that, otherwise 5 is your go-to solution. Leaving comments is fine, but if you spot the problem, it usually implies you know (part of) the solution, in that case please share that as well, which leads back to 3 and 5.

Comment: Is this about answers that offer bad solutions (ie code that would not be accessible) or about answers about any topic that are themselves not accessible?

Comment: What @Laurel says - I already wrote a couple of paragraphs assuming the latter; it makes little sense if it's the former (but then your question is probably better off at Meta Stack Overflow).

Comment: It is mainly about answers that offer inaccessible solutions, while perfectly solving the issue the questioner knew they had (;
But there are sometimes also questions that are looking for details of a solution in itself is not accessible. Does this respond to your second option?

Comment: @Glorfindel I figured this was the right place since this also concerns the UX StackExchange, but yes, it’s mainly about SO

Comment: It's not really any different than handling any other type of bad but superficially ok code (e.g. SQL injection). See also this question about [irresponsible answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38632/323179) and another about [dangerous code in a question and its  answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161040/323179).

Comment: **To close vote reviewers:** As this appears relate to more than one site (though really only a couple), it is **still on-topic** for Meta SE. If it can *only* relate to one site, it would be closeable.

Comment: Thanks @Rob, these are about the SE platform. I’m talking about the content, the answers given on the platform.

Comment: I gathered from comments 2,3&4, and the accessibility tag, that this was about content [tag:accessibility]; indeed this would apply to many sites; an edit clearly stating the objective would be helpful.

Comment: Re *"learn developing"* Despite popular belief, that is only incidental and not the (current) purpose of Stack Overflow. Though hopefully the company will launch some new ground-breaking product in the future to address the learning part as there is very clearly a need for it. It should probably be more than [a simple split](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390983).

Comment: I wonder if this would work better as a feature request. Perhaps there should be an accessibility review queue?

Comment: @LShaver:  I was told this by my own accessibility review team where I work.  One as a sighted person cannot reliably test something for accessibility, because you don't actually *use* the site in the same way.  It's a totally different ball game, and given Stack Exchange's track record with queues, I couldn't trust anyone here with a queue as saying that their code is "accessible".

Comment: @Makoto on re-reading the question, I think I mis-understood. I was thinking of a queue that would address questions and answers which had accessibility issues (no image alt-text, headings using bold rather than the heading markdown, etc.) This would assume that all Q&A content *could* be made accessible, but that it takes a bit of work. But I see the question is about whether the code included in an answer is accessible, which is probably outside of the scope of any SE site.

Comment: What is an accessible answer? An answer that describes images that are linked to instead of just linking to them? Or can code itself somehow be more or less accessible?

Comment: @forestdistrustsStackExchange An example would be an answer that messes up keyboard navigation: https://focus.hteumeuleu.com

Comment: @forestdistrustsStackExchange Though answers that can't be understood without the images that also lack alt text aren't good either.

Answer (score 17):

I'm of the acute position that if someone elects to blatantly copy an answer from Stack Overflow, then they're already not testing for accessibility.

[We already don't issue any warranty for the code we submit in answers, and we don't guarantee it fit for any purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#warranties). Why should we change this by adding something for accessibility in answers?  Then we're stating that it's fit for *some* purpose!

Comment: +1 Example code should illustrate the answer, not be a template if the perfect way to implement something. If I'm trying to understand how to bind a function to a Widget A event, I don't need an explanation of how those widgets have accessibility issues, especially since it's difficult to understand the extent of and best remedy for a potential issue with such limited context.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not how most people use the site.
Most people blindly copy the code, never reference neither the source, nor the author in their code, and they do not even consider that there might be conditions that apply. I got insulted for mentioning that all the code on stack overflow was published under a license.

Comment: @Andy: Yes, I'm aware of this.  *Acutely* aware of this.  This doesn't change my position since it shifts the responsibility of the quality and fitness of the code *away* from the only party that matters in the equation.

Comment: Nonetheless, it's important to include any major "gotchas" caused by using the answer as-is.  People coming to Stack Overflow for code can't be expected to understand every possible downside to an answer, even if they're not blatantly copying answers.  Someone seeing a highly upvoted answer may reasonably think it's the "correct" way to do things, when actually it's a hack that should never be used in production.

Answer (score 4):

The Stack Exchange network is a network of Q&A sites where the information provided is determined and limited by the question parameters.<sup>♧</sup>

What follows is that the only thing one can really do to raise awareness about and provide solutions for more inclusive solutions is to **incorporate accessibility into a question, or provide good answers that go that extra mile**.

Sure, commenting might nudge some users to revise their questions or answers, but this cannot be forced.

---

<sup>♧ And site scope and policy, and tag descriptions.</sup>

Comment: This was 'inspired' by Makoto's great answer.

Answer (score -2):

I firmly believe in accessible software. That's software for as many people as possible. In particular, software that doesn't kick people to the curb for having a disability.

When software is accessible, all users benefit.

An answer that gives a solution with fundamental accessibility problems is not a very good answer. That is, the answers written in such a way that anyone following the answer will produce inaccessible software.

If we want to get technical, such an answer might provide clickable spans, which have a number of accessibility problems, the biggest of which is that keyboard users cannot interact with them. (Keyboard users include the visually impaired who use screen readers and even power users who may find it easier on their hands to use a keyboard.) But there are more problems — a clickable span may look like a link but it doesn't behave like one, so no right clicking to open it in a new tab, or do anything like that.

Yes, accessibility can be hard, but these are supposed to be sites for *expert* answers.

Handling these answers is the same as any other not good answer:

- Downvote!

  - For maximum benefit, you should leave a comment explaining why
- Upvote correct, accessible answers
- Write your own better answer if you can. Explain why it's better.

I looked back at an answer I downvoted last year for accessibility problems, and some of those techniques above allowed a more accessible answer to reach the top voted spot. The new trending option may also help better answers get more visibility.

Typically such answers are not flagged, and usually banners are not edited into them mentioning their problems.

---

For questions, if the accessibility issue isn't at the core of what it's asking, you can leave a comment pointing out what's wrong. Downvote if you see fit — or not. Having highly visible questions about "how to do [bad thing]" are valuable when they have answers that say "don't" and offer a better alternative.

Comment: An answer which doesn't account for accessibility concerns in the context of there not being an explicit request for them is not "dangerous" by any stretch of the imagination.  For instance, if someone is asking on how to load some form in a web framework, an appropriate (and thus useful) answer would be one that tells them to do just that.  Downvoting it because it overlooks any hallmarks of accessibility is disingenuous and sends the exact wrong message that their answer was incorrect, when at *best* it could be argued "incomplete", but very weakly.

Comment: @Makoto I can change it to a wording that you prefer, but the danger is very real: app/website accessibility lawsuits number in the 10 000s per year in the US according to the [American Bar](https://www.americanbar.org/groups/law_practice/publications/law_practice_magazine/2022/jf22/vu-launey-egan/).

Comment: ...and yet, I wouldn't quantify that as a danger in the same fashion as I would SQL injection.  But again, my point is more or less centered around what it is we on Stack Overflow are actually responsible for.  We wouldn't write an SQL query with string replacement - that's kinda drilled into us at this point. Not many of us know how to write a website that's accessible or meets certain accessibility requirements, which should entirely be its own extra question.

Comment: In the end, to get digital products right, we need disciplines to collaborate. e.g. a security expert, and an accessibility expert etc. The same counts for the little pieces of the product, which are found on SE, right? In this sense maybe we should seek to collaborate on answers, and detach them from single persons. On the other hand, the gamification is what keeps SE running.

Comment: @Andy:  Sure, we need disciplines to collaborate, but that's beyond my pay grade here on the Stack Exchange network.  Someone asks a question, someone gets an answer, and of *course* there is a laundry list of caveats to it.  Only the experts pay attention to that laundry list, but it's ultimately **not my responsibility** to be sure that a user accounts for *every* scenario.  It'd be a jerk move of me to *introduce* bad practices, but I'm not going to go out of my way to ensure that the code I write adheres to every accessibility standard out there.

Comment: @Makoto I'm afraid I don't understand what you're advocating. Are you saying that I shouldn't downvote answers that have accessibility problems? Because writing an answer without accessibility problems is too difficult? What is the exact criticism you have of the steps I've outlined?

Comment: @Laurel:  If you're presented with an answer that does not deal with any accessibility problems and the question has not *explicitly* asked for it to deal with accessibility problems, then it is disingenuous to downvote it, or treat it as dangerous.  If the question *explicitly* expects accessibility help and the answer doesn't provide it, then downvoting is fine since by definition, the answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Makoto Why? So that people can write software that disabled people can't use? Do we just assume that the code is for the private pet project of the asker (and then why make it secure either)?

Comment: @Makoto If someone asks a question about CSS animation, they shouldn't have to explicitly state that none of the answers should contain animation that triggers a seizure.

Comment: @BSMP: That's a false equivalence.  The subject matter of making things accessible is very nuanced and has different standards.  Depending on the screen reader you're using, you may not be able to reliably account for every scenario (I know that JAWS and NVDA disagree in certain parts on certain things at certain times).  Much like browsers, places have to choose which screen reader technology they elect to support because screen reader technology still acts like it's 2005 when it comes to compatibility.  So just asking me to "support accessibility" is a crapshoot when you didn't ask about it.

Comment: That’s why I’m using “foundational accessibility issues”. The large majority of suggested solutions doesn’t work in either screen reader. Take Images with missing alt attributes for example. Or Buttons with no text, inputs with no labels at all.

Comment: @Laurel:  That's not the point of this.  The answerer is ***not*** accountable unto the accessibility of any code that is written here; the ***asker*** is.  If the asker does not inquire about accessibility, it is entirely out of scope for me to include it as a part of my answer.

Comment: Yes @Andy, but you make my point.  If one wants us to help them with making things compatible with any such screen reader, they need to be ***explicit*** about it.  There are differences.  There are things that are tolerable.  We don't know what those things are just because we put some code on the site, and we can ***never*** know those things unless we are explicitly told what someone wants.  Only way that happens is - you guessed it - if they explicitly ask us.  If they don't, I'm not going to ever put the expectation on someone to write it into their answer.

Comment: @Makoto It's not a false equivalence; I'd have to be making a comparison for that to be true. You're arguing that people shouldn't downvote answers with accessibility problems without the question specifically asking about it and I pointed out an *accessibility issue* that shouldn't have to be explicitly stated. Your argument that all accessibility issues should be ignored does not make sense.

Comment: @Makoto I'm not sure why an accessibility problem is different than any other problem with an answer. Should we also not care about pointing out answers that only mask a bug, rather than fixing it, if the asker doesn't specify that the answer should actually solve the root cause?  Should we not point out issues that could cause other harmful side-effects, like [wiping your home directory](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/649408/77374), if the asker doesn't say that it should correctly handle errors? Should we ignore disabling SSL security entirely if the asker doesn't say the code should be secure?

Comment: @RyanM:  Because accessibility issues aren't as straightforward as other issues.  They are specialized issues that most sighted users simply cannot identify at "a glance".  I work at an institution that does require and mandate ADA requirements, but I need a different machine to test things on (a Windows laptop to run JAWS/NVDA since I work on Linux).  **You cannot put the requirement on an answerer** to "point out" an accessibility issue because they may not be in a position to, and unless the asker is requiring it, it is **disingenuous** to treat it as an "incorrect" answer.

Comment: @Makoto But there's a comment that points out the accessibility problem (see my sub bullet). The correct course of action is for the answerer to read it, understand the issue, and fix it. Why should I not use the tools given to me for the purpose they're for? Do we really need to accommodate incomplete, flawed answers on a site for expert answers?

Comment: @Laurel:  In the sense of answering the question the OP asks, saying that "oh, you forgot this detail that the OP didn't inquire about" is noisy.  Sure, it can be beneficial noise.  But I wouldn't want to compel anyone to make such noise unless they were certain.  What's worse is that the answerer wouldn't be able to independently confirm your findings unless you provided a similar setup or scope.  All this because they wanted to help someone with getting a button to do something besides click.

Comment: @Laurel:  I'll make my position clear - unless the OP explicitly asks about it, punishing answerers over accessibility concerns with their answers is a bridge too far.  Commenting to them that their answer isn't accessible doesn't help them since they may not be able to verify that.  This is entirely **too much work** for a volunteer as opposed to the OP who is actually responsible for doing this at all.

Comment: @Makoto I think we might be talking past each other. I'm talking about answers that add accessibility problems so fundamentally flawed that they should never be used in a production app. Telling people to add `tools:ignore` to warnings to add content descriptions on Android, for example, rather than telling people how to add a content description. Telling people to add click handling with a gesture listener rather than a click listener. These things should *never* be done in a production app. They aren't nice extra features; they are the **bare minimum** for everyone to be able to use an app.

Comment: @RyanM:  Gonna say that's really not our responsibility either.  If someone decides to accept an answer that is flawed in some way, but not in the way that it doesn't cause them explicit heartburn, then I don't know if it's really our place to do anything about that.  Yes, there's the desire to not give some horribly wrong answer, but if the OP doesn't ask about accessibility, I really don't see a reason to introduce it or mitigate unknown concerns around it.

Comment: Is disabling SSL security also not our place to point out, then? Correctly validating SSL certificates is subtle and difficult to get right (and requires installing extra software to test, unlike mobile accessibility problems), and it'll definitely solve whatever SSL verification error the asker has. Are SQL injection vulnerabilities also okay? The asker's sample data doesn't have any quotes in it, so it'll work on that. What about wiping the working directory if a folder doesn't exist? The asker never explicitly said the directory might not exist.

Comment: What about incomplete fixes? There are lots of crashes (caused by improper handling of configuration changes) on Android that *mostly* happen on screen rotation, because that's a common config change. You can ignore that change (a commonly suggested fix!) but it'll still crash on *other* config changes. Should we not downvote that too if the asker only mentioned screen rotation, since it doesn't crash *then*?

Comment: Using what the asker (who often *does not understand the problem*, and is thus the worst person to determine what matters for a solution) did and did not think to ask about to determine what does and does not matter is a mistake. We are not a helpdesk. We're here to provide the *most correct solution* for the *next* person who has a similar problem.